# Pass multiple elements of multiple lists to a function in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

How can I pass multiple element another function named `testResults()`:

```
elem1 =  map(int, result[2])
elem2 = map(int, result[3])
length = len(elem1)
```

`testResults(elem1[0],elem2[0])` then `testResults(elem1[1],elem2[1])` ... to `testResults(elem1[length],elem2[length])`

And function testResults arguments are defined like:

```
def testResults(num, place, code='test'):
    ....
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Just do `for i in zip(elem1, elem2): testResults(*i)`

Comment: @VHarisop, that works of course (and you should make it an answer: "don't answer in comments" is a SO principle!-), I just think that my similar solution (explicitly naming the two items) is more readable -- per `import this`, "explicit is better than implicit":-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli I hadn't seen your answer when I posted this. Yours is naturally more readable, but I will make it an answer if you insist :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to Alex Martelli's (obviously more readable) solution, you can use `zip` along with `*` for unpacking the tuple and passing each tuple element to the function:

```
for pair in zip(elem1, elem2):
    testResults(*pair) # unpack pair here
```

Answer (score 1):

The `zip` built-in seems to be what you want:

```
for num, place in zip(elem1, elem2):
    testResults(num, place)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use zip: as the soln given by Alex

```
for num, place in zip(elem1, elem2):
    testResults(num, place)
```

or you can use this simple approach:

```
for i in range(len(elem1)):
    testResults(elem1[i], elem2[i])
```